# Project and Project task view by related user or group only

Tags: vtiger

If I want to modify the code with this function, any idea to help me? Where should I change the code? or vtiger already having this function? How to setting on profile there?

### Question

1)Project and Project task view by related user or group only, not for everyone can view all the project. If this project are related to the user, only show to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to CRM setting-> Sharing Access->change privileges and select Private from dropdown. And Make sure you have to recalculate the sharing access by click on recalculate button.